# Generating PDF from JSON using java

Tags: java, html, json, xml, xslt

I have a requirement to generate PDF from JSON. For that i tried the following steps to generate PDF,

first, i parsed JSON to XML, then from XML to HTML conversion and finally generated PDF from HTML.

Please find my code below., its working fine.

```
Transformer transformer;
    try {
        transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer(new StreamSource(new File(xslPath)));
    } catch (TransformerConfigurationException | TransformerFactoryConfigurationError e1) {
        throw ExceptionUtils.handle((Exception) e1);
    }

    DOMResult result = new DOMResult();

    try {
        transformer.transform(new StreamSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"))), result);
    } catch (TransformerException e) {
        throw ExceptionUtils.handle(e);
    }

    ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
    try {
        renderer.getFontResolver().addFont("C:/WINDOWS/FONTS/ARIAL.TTF", true);
    } catch (DocumentException e) {
        throw ExceptionUtils.handle(e);
    }

    Document resultDoc = (Document) result.getNode();
    renderer.setDocument(resultDoc, "");
    renderer.layout();
```

Its generating PDF in `Portrait` but, i want that PDF should generate in `Landscape` mode. For that i  have to modify `HTML` code bit.

I have to integrate below piece of code to make my PDF in `Landscape` mode

```
    XMLResource res = XMLResource
            .load(new StringReader("<html><head><style>@page { size : 29.7cm 21cm; }</style></head><body></body></html>"));
```

But, am not sure where i can inject this piece of code in my existing code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Add these styles to the head of the Xhtml you are building**

1: for portrait :@page {size: letter portrait;}

2: for landscape : @page {size: letter landscape;